# Questions about hyperplane and general position from book by Joe Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have trouble with the argument of this proof:

> Theorem 1.4: If $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is any collection of $d\leq 2n$ points in general position, then $\Gamma$ may be described as the zero locus of quadratic polynomials.

Here general position means no $n+1$ or fewer points of $\Gamma$ are dependent.

Then the proof involves the argument that in the case $\Gamma$ has exactly 2n points, if we write $\Gamma = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ where $\Gamma_i$ has n points, then each $\Gamma_i$ will span a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$, and I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: Do you understand why $2$ points in $\Bbb P^2$ are on a line? How about why $3$ points in $\Bbb P^3$ are on a plane?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, so does that mean n points always span a hyperplane and this has nothing to do with $\Gamma$ being in general position...?

Comment: General position is essential for $2$ points to span a line, $3$ points to span a plane, etc.

Comment: (I should clarify - $n$ points in $\Bbb P^n$ are always *on* a hyperplane, but only span a *unique* hyperplane iff they're in general position.)